# How fix this ?? always asked to change constructor --> mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have 3 class

- Main Class
- Fragment (Pager)
- Fragment Adapter

but, in fragment, there's problem, anybody can help me ??

```
public class AttractionFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Solo", "Karanganyar", "Sukoharjo" };

public AttractionFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction, container, false);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

        //This my problem
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and this my adapter class

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new SoloAttractionFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new KaranganyarAttractionFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new SukoharjoAttractionFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: still error, after i change to mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); , [ The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type AttractionFragment ]

Comment: well you need to use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` and your imports must be from support library

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type 
  Activity
 - The constructor TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined

Comment: what is your min sdk in manifest file??

Comment: still error, after i change to mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html. you are using this from support library but your min sdk is 14?

Comment: so, how many i should use ?? 19 ?? :O , i'm a new with fragment, so tell me how i have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

You may also want to check

[Does the Android ICS API have a native equivalent to ViewPager support lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958013/does-the-android-ics-api-have-a-native-equivalent-to-viewpager-support-lib)

You need to change a lot of things.

In Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_view);
        AttractionFragment newFragment = new AttractionFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
 }
 }
```

AttractionFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AttractionFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Solo", "Karanganyar", "Sukoharjo","Sragen","Boyolali","Klaten","Wonogiri"  };

public AttractionFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

        //This my problem
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(AttractionFragment.this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

TabsPageAdapter

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public TabsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (index) {

    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        fragment =new SoloAttractionFragment();

    case 1:
        fragment = new KaranganyarAttractionFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        fragment = new SukoharjoAttractionFragment();
    }

    return fragment ;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
}
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: still error, I was feeling dizzy, previously, I followed the tutorial from androidhive.info , then I modified because I use navigation tabs with drawer and swipe.

Comment: @YeftaAndrea what else do you want. posted code. psoted snap shot. What is the error.

Comment: please, I've uploaded on dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/vdxy6giip7r5p4a/yefta.rar

Comment: @YeftaAndrea you haven't followed by post at all and you say you still get error

Comment: i'm sorry, but thanks a lot for help me @Raghunandan , I already know the solution, I found I had to remove import fragment because i have to use fragment v4, but thanks a lot :)

Comment: but actually your answers was not yet successful, but the outline is the same :D okay

Comment: @YeftaAndrea my answer is alright. See the import statements. I already posted. Also if supporting 14 then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958013/does-the-android-ics-api-have-a-native-equivalent-to-viewpager-support-lib

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
```

with

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(android.app.FragmentManager.FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
```

Try not to use support fragment manager.

No it won't give error, as i have tried with below sample code.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public MainActivity(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: if i change like that, in line super(fm) will show error notification to change source code like before.